# Big Query String Manipulation using SubQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would appreciate a push in the right direction with how this might be achieved using GCP Big Query, please.

I have a column in my table of type string, inside this string there are a repeating sequence of characters and I need to extract and process each of them. To illustrate, lets say the column name is 'instruments'. A possible value for instruments could be:

'band=false;inst=basoon,inst=cello;inst=guitar;cases=false,permits=false'

In which case I need to extract 'basoon', 'cello' and 'guitar'.

I'm more or less a SQL newbie, sorry. So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    bandId,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(instruments, r'inst=.*?\;') AS INSTS
   
FROM `inventory.band.mytable`;
```

This extracts the instruments substring ('inst=basoon,inst=cello;inst=guitar;') and gives me an output column 'INSTS' but now I think I need to split the values in that column on the comma and do some further processing. This is where I'm stuck as I cannot see how to structure additional queries or processing blocks.

How can I reference the INSTS in order to do subsequent processing? Documentation suggests I should be buildin subqueries using WITH but I can't seem to get anything going. Could some kind soul give me a push in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has a function `SPLIT()` that does the same as `SPLIT_PART()` in other databases.

Assuming that you don't alternate between the comma and the semicolon for separating your «key»=«value» pairs, and only use the semicolon,
first you split your `instruments` string into as many parts that contain `inst=`. To do that, you use an in-line table of consecutive integers to `CROSS JOIN` with, so that you can `SPLIT(instruments,';',i)` with an increasing integer value for `i`.  You will get strings in the format `inst=%`, of which you want the part after the equal sign. You get that part by applying another `SPLIT()`, this time with the equal sign as the delimiter, and for the second split part:

```
WITH indata(bandid,instruments) AS (                                                                                                                                                         
-- some input, don't use in real query ...
-- I assume that you don't alternate between comma and semicolon for the delimiter, and stick to semicolon
  SELECT
  1,'band=false;inst=basoon;inst=cello;inst=guitar;cases=false;permits=false'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  2,'band=true;inst=drum;inst=cello;inst=bass;inst=flute;cases=false;permits=true'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  3,'band=false;inst=12string;inst=banjo;inst=triangle;inst=tuba;cases=false;permits=true'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH" ...
,
-- need a series of consecutive integers ...
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 
)
SELECT
  bandid
, i
, SPLIT(SPLIT(instruments,';',i),'=',2) AS instrument
FROM indata CROSS JOIN i
WHERE SPLIT(instruments,';',i) like 'inst=%'
ORDER BY 1
-- out  bandid | i | instrument 
-- out --------+---+------------
-- out       1 | 2 | basoon
-- out       1 | 3 | cello
-- out       1 | 4 | guitar
-- out       2 | 2 | drum
-- out       2 | 3 | cello
-- out       2 | 4 | bass
-- out       2 | 5 | flute
-- out       3 | 2 | 12string
-- out       3 | 3 | banjo
-- out       3 | 4 | triangle
-- out       3 | 5 | tuba
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below few options (just to demonstrate different technics here)

Option 1

```
select bandId, 
  ( select string_agg(split(kv, '=')[offset(1)])
    from unnest(split(instruments, ';')) kv
    where split(kv, '=')[offset(0)] = 'inst'
  ) as insts
from `inventory.band.mytable`
```

Option 2  (for obvious reason this one would be my choice)

```
select bandId, 
  array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(instruments, r'inst=([^;$]+)'), ',') instrs 
from `inventory.band.mytable`
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output in both cases is

[image]